# Python MEMORY ERROR when loading 2455 CSV files (42GB) as pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Good day, I have 42Gb of data in a list of sequenced 2455 xCSV files. 
I am trying to import the data sequentially using a loop into a `pd.DataFrame` for analysis.
I have tried it with 3 files and it works well.

```
from glob import glob
import pandas as pd

# Import data into DF
filenames = glob('Z:\PersonalFolders\AllData\*.csv')
df_trial = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames]
df_trial
```

I am getting the following error. Copy pasted the traceback here. Please help

```
df_trial = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-23-0438182db491>", line 1, in <module>
    df_trial = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames]

  File "<ipython-input-23-0438182db491>", line 1, in <listcomp>
    df_trial = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames]

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1148, in read
    df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 435, in __init__
    mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 254, in init_dict
    return arrays_to_mgr(arrays, data_names, index, columns, dtype=dtype)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 74, in arrays_to_mgr
    return create_block_manager_from_arrays(arrays, arr_names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1670, in create_block_manager_from_arrays
    blocks = form_blocks(arrays, names, axes)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1726, in form_blocks
    float_blocks = _multi_blockify(items_dict["FloatBlock"])

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1820, in _multi_blockify
    values, placement = _stack_arrays(list(tup_block), dtype)

  File "C:\Users\WorkStation\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1848, in _stack_arrays
    stacked = np.empty(shape, dtype=dtype)

MemoryError: Unable to allocate 107. MiB for an array with shape (124, 113012) and data type float64
```

Comment: Well said. I have 32GB. Still short.. Thanks.

Comment: You may want to explore memory mapped files: see https://het.as.utexas.edu/HET/Software/Numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things you can do.

First, only process one dataframe at a time:

```py
filenames = glob('Z:\PersonalFolders\AllData\*.csv')
for f in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(f)
    process(df)
```

Second, if that's not possible you can try to reduce the amount of memory used when loading the dataframes by a variety of means (smaller dtypes for numeric columns, omitting numeric columns, and more). See https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pandas-load-less-data/ for some starting points on these techniques.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all.

I was able to process all 42GB of data using the nrows argument

```
filenames = glob('Z:\PersonalFolders\AllData\*.csv')

df_2019=[]
for filename in filenames:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0, nrows = 1000)
    df_2019.append(df)

frame = pd.concat(df_2019, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```